# Clear History in GWT MVP

Tags: gwt, history, mvp

I have followed [this](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces) tutorial from google developers and I built an application based on activities and places. As tutorial suggests, I use history Handler.

I created a "clear history" button, but I can't find any way to clear history.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it`s not possible to clear the history because the history is handled by the browser and for security reason you are only able to add a history item, replace the current history item or go back in history